# If I use Type-C OTG usb HUB + micro Type-B adapter from Type-C, will OTG work through that adapter?

Tags: usb-on-the-go

If I use Type-C OTG usb HUB + micro Type-B adapter which goes from Type-C, will OTG work through that adapter? I mean, like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32959371116.html?spm=2114.search0302.3.38.133d6a49dG6fHS&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=4318bacf-1174-4552-b564-96094f966e93&algo_expid=4318bacf-1174-4552-b564-96094f966e93-5) + [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-3-1-Type-C-Female-to-Micro-USB-Male-Data-Adapter-Connector-Converter-USB-C-/371979929960).

Comment: With USB-C OTG has become much simpler as you don't need special OTG hardware anymore. Therefore I don't see a reason why this should not work.

Comment: I just edited the 1st link. Now I put link with Type-C HUB. I mean, that I have devices with both B and C type, so I want to be able to use usb C type hub with B compatible devices also and asking if it should work through that adapter. I want hub because I want to be able to charge my device while using mouse with keyboard

Comment: Does your phone have an USB-C or Micro-USB port? What I said is for a phone with USB-C port.

Comment: I have few devices which are with C and Micro and I want to be able to use both devices with the same HUB.

Comment: Please answer my question about the USB port of your phone as it makes a significant difference.

Comment: I recently ordered a phone with C Type but I often use OTG cable with tablet which is Micro

Comment: There is no general answer, USB-C OTG is totally different from Micro USB OTG. Therefore please ask for one of them but not for both. The solution for the one may work for the other but that is not for sure.

Comment: Actually I see no problem of buying two different HUBs for both devices and I don't think that exist a different way. Everywhere I see adapters like https://www.amazon.com/Duttek-Adapter-Converter-Charging-Silver-OTG/dp/B06X9M6T99 or https://www.amazon.co.uk/Female-Adapter-Charging-Converter-Camera-TypeC-Male-Micro/dp/B07BBCS5JT which has included in description that charging and OTG can't be used at the same time, so this is not acceptable for me.